# Filter and sum a second colunmn by filter context

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with a CompanyID, PartnerCompanyID and Sales. If the customer is a group partner company, a further PartnerCompanyID column is filled with the CompanyID of the internal customer.

I’d like to sum the sales but only for sales other than internal sales between the companies within the filter context. That is the sales with no (empty) PartnerCompanyIDs or with PartnerCompanyIDs other than the CompanyID’s within the filter context.

[Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSiJG.png)

I tried with

```
SalesExtern = CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[Sales]);Filter(Sales;NOT(CONTAINS(ALLSELECTED(Company[CompanyID]);Company[CompanyID];LASTNONBLANK(Sales[PartnerCompanyID];"")))))
```

The sum seems to be ok, but the values per line are wrong:

[Model2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4yiG.png)

[PBIX File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18DfAFGZkaXCeAT2ofgFHc-x7ebwg8SJA/view?usp=sharing)

thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not something much simpler like this?

```
SalesExtern = CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[Sales]);
                  FILTER(Sales; ISBLANK(Sales[PartnerCompanyID])))
```

---

**Edit:** Try this instead.

Create a duplicate table of `Company` using New Table under Modeling:

```
PartnerCompany = Company
```

Create a relationship from `PartnerCompany[CompanyID]` to `Sales[ParterCompanyID]`.

Define your new measure as follows:

```
ExternalSales = 
    VAR SelectedClusters = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Company[Cluster]), ALLSELECTED(Sales))
    RETURN CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[Sales]), NOT(PartnerCompany[Cluster] IN SelectedClusters))
```

Comment: There are few companies grouped in clusters. The sales table is filtered via the cluster (CompanyID: CompanyID). It can happen that PartnerCompanyID is not empty, but it does not belong to one of the filtered clusters, so the record belongs to the externalSales and has to be counted. I hope I have described it understandable :)

Comment: @A.Golenko OK, I think I understand. I spent quite a while trying to figure out how to use both relationships at the same time, but couldn't get anything that quite worked. I've added a simple workaround that might help you.

Comment: Wow! Thank you! That's it. I had the idea with the second table too, but did not know how to use both relationships.